# How to dynamically convert strings in an array into variables using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

In order to find the largest dataset among others and concatenate them, I'm sorting them by their lengths.

Now, I'd like to concatenate them, but I'd need to turn these strings into the variable name, so that I can iterate through each of these datasets, concatenating them.

I've seen that `window[]` is used in JavaScript, but what about in GAS?

```
function concatenateData() {
  let dataSizes = [];

  //Separated datasets
  let finalFabricData = [
    ["A", "C", 3],
    ["S", "R", 4],
    ["C", "O", 3]
  ];
  dataSizes.push('finalFabricData', finalFabricData.length);

  let finalDecorationData = [
    ["T", "D", 3],
    ["F", "F", 4],
    ["G", "O", 3]
  ];;
  dataSizes.push('finalDecorationData', finalDecorationData.length)

  let finalHtData = [
    ["A", "C", 3],
    ["S", "R", 4],
    ["K", "O", 3]
  ];
  dataSizes.push('finalHtData', finalHtData.length);

  let finalOrderData = [
    ["Z", "C", 3]
  ];
  dataSizes.push('finalOrderData', finalOrderData.length);

  //Attempt to grab the variable names, but they come as strings
  let data1 = dataSizes[0][0];
  let data2 = dataSizes[1][0];
  let data3 = dataSizes[2][0];
  let data4 = dataSizes[3][0];

  //Attempt to concatenate them, but data1 is not iterable
  let finalDataset = [];
  data1.forEach(function(row, i) {
    row = row.concat(data2[i], data3[i], data4[i]);
    finalDataset.push(row)
  });
}
```

**Exected Result**

```
let res = [
  ["A", "C", 3, "T", "D", 3, "A", "C", 3, "Z", "C", 3],
  ["S", "R", 4, "F", "F", 4, "S", "R", 4, "", "", ""],
  ["C", "O", 3, "G", "O", 3, "K", "O", 3, "", "", ""]
];
```

Comment: Can you provide your expected output values? By the way, your input values are `finalFabricData`, `finalDecorationData`, `finalHtData`, `finalOrderData`, `datasetIndexLength`?

Comment: I've just edited the question to both try to explain it more clearly and to display an expected result. Thanks, @Tanaike!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding your expected values. From your expected values, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
// These are from your script.
let finalFabricData = [
  ["A", "C", 3],
  ["S", "R", 4],
  ["C", "O", 3]
];
let finalDecorationData = [
  ["T", "D", 3],
  ["F", "F", 4],
  ["G", "O", 3]
];;
let finalHtData = [
  ["A", "C", 3],
  ["S", "R", 4],
  ["K", "O", 3]
];
let finalOrderData = [
  ["Z", "C", 3]
];

// I modified the below script.
const arrays = [finalFabricData, finalDecorationData, finalHtData, finalOrderData];
const res = arrays[0].map((_, c) => arrays.flatMap(r => r[c] || Array(3).fill("")));
console.log(res)
```

- When this script is run, your expected values are retrieved.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! One question: The length of these datasets may vary. ```finalDecorationData``` may have 5 rows and that would become the base dataset that others would get concatenated to. This is why I push the variable name and its length into ```dataSizes``` so that I can grab the one with max rows. Now grabbing the largest dataset dynamically, which is then a string in the first column in ```dataSizes``` is my challenge. Thank you!

Comment: @onit Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand your reply. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your reply? By this, I would like to try to understand your reply.

Comment: A piece missing requires me to ```eval()```and your solution does build the end result as expected. Thank you!!!!